# Can Socket.io handle to send 1KB data to 1M users in every seconds without delay?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

Can [Socket.io](https://socket.io) handle to send 1KB data to 1M users in every seconds without delay?
 If it can handle, what should be server requirements (Cpu, Ram)?
 If not, what is the better choose to delivery 1KB data for 1M users in every seconds without delay?

Thanks

Comment: It means 1GB/s of internet transfer

Comment: Yes, it is. And so, do you think as socket.io can handle for 1M socket connection in every seconds?